# Python sqlite3 order error

Tags: python, sqlite

So, I am trying to understand this:

```
    c.execute('SELECT * FROM random ORDER BY id')
    line = c.fetchall()
    for row in line:
        text.insert(END, row)
        text.insert(END, '\n')
```

With the Sqlite3 list:

```
1 7

2 94

3 15
```

(The first number is a simple id (line number for example) and the second number is just a random number)
Now, I have a problem...When I add the the id 11 and when i print row it gives me this:

```
('1', 7)

('11', 60)

('2', 94)

('3', 15)
```

The number 11 was supposed to appear last, right?

Any help?

Comment: What data type is `id`?  Is it numeric or character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your output you have quotes around 11: `'11'` -- it means it is a string of 11. Somehow, you need to make sure you store integers in id field.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the column `id` is of type `char`, so the order is correct, because the string `11` is lower than 2. You should change the type of column id to `int` or you have to conver id before ordering